# NullPointerException when adding some LinearLayouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, nullpointerexception

I'm developing an Android app which requires me to define some `LinearLayouts` contained inside a main `LinearLayout`, these layouts data are dynamically obtained through the run_time, but the Container Layout is statically declared in the XML, I add the dynamically created Layouts to the main Layout but i got a `NullPointerException` :

```
02-13 11:03:45.745: WARN/System.err(620): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 11:03:45.745: WARN/System.err(620):     at com.example.solaceap.Media.initiatePopupWindow(Media.java:476)
02-13 11:03:45.755: WARN/System.err(620):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
02-13 11:03:45.765: WARN/System.err(620):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
02-13 11:03:45.765: WARN/System.err(620):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-13 11:03:45.765: WARN/System.err(620):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-13 11:03:45.775: WARN/System.err(620):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 11:03:45.785: WARN/System.err(620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-13 11:03:45.785: WARN/System.err(620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 11:03:45.795: WARN/System.err(620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 11:03:45.795: WARN/System.err(620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-13 11:03:45.805: WARN/System.err(620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-13 11:03:45.805: WARN/System.err(620):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**and This is my code :**

main Layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/music_popup"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp" >
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the dynamically declared layouts:

```
   private View layout = null;
   LinearLayout music_pop_up = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.music_popup);
   private void initiatePopupWindow(String section) {
                    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_popup,
                            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.music_pop));

                    // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
                    pw = new PopupWindow(layout,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                    // display the popup in the center
                    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                    music_cancel = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.back_music);
                    music_cancel.setOnClickListener(onCancelClick);

                    get_music_albums();
    }
    public void get_music_albums(){
        int albums_num = albums_arr.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < albums_num; i++){
                LinearLayout music_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
                music_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                music_layout.setLayoutParams(music_lp);
                music_pop_up.addView(music_layout); // this is where i got the Exception

                ImageButton poster = new ImageButton(this);
                poster.setTag(i);
                poster.setLayoutParams(album_lp);
                music_layout.addView(poster);
                poster.setClickable(true);
                poster.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                poster.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                poster.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                poster.setImageResource(R.drawable.media_poster);

                TextView album_name = new TextView(this);
                album_name.setLayoutParams(album_name_lp);
                music_layout.addView(album_name);
                album_name.setTextSize(13);
                album_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                album_name.setText("test");

                TextView artist_name = new TextView(this);
                artist_name.setLayoutParams(artist_name_lp);
                music_layout.addView(artist_name);
                artist_name.setTextSize(8);
                artist_name.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                artist_name.setText("test");
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how i declare the layout params:

```
        // Declaring the Music LayoutParams
        music_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
        music_lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        music_lp.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);

        // Declaring the Album LayoutParams
        album_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        album_lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        album_lp.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);

        // Declaring the Album_Name LayoutParams
        album_name_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        album_name_lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        // Declaring the Artist_Name LayoutParams
        artist_name_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        artist_name_lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

Comment: but where you added your dynamically created Layout into your main container Layout?

Comment: @MD sorry for that i forgot to add the first line, now look at the updates

Comment: Put this line at last of u r for loop  `music_pop_up.addView(music_layout); // this is where i got the Exception`

Comment: yea i tried that before, and also tried to put the lines of adding Views(ImageButton, 2 TextViews)on the last and also nothing

Comment: post u r all code plz. becoz it seems like perfect. u got error at different location

Comment: @MD well, look at the updates, this is the whole code of this process

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47418/discussion-between-m-d-and-mrefaat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're not building the views correctly, 
**initiatePopupWindow(Media.java:476)** crashes in line 476
If you don't know the size of linear layout consider using listview and recycle your views in there.

If you can't use listview debug your class in this line and check why it's still null.

Comment: after debugging I found that the `music_pop_up` Layout is the one that gives me that `NullPointerException` due to it's null , and that happens because I'm declaring it before initiating the pop-up window and that make it doesn't created yet.

Answer (score 1):

First try this you should change this

```
 layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_popup,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.music_pop));
```

With

```
 LayoutInflater layout ;
 layout = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 View v = layout.inflate(R.layout.music_popup, null);
```

Comment: it gives me that exception :

`02-13 12:19:34.246: WARN/WindowManager(89): Failed looking up window
02-13 12:19:34.246: WARN/WindowManager(89): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window null does not exist`

on that line : 
    `pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);`

Comment: @MRefaat try to come on chat

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LayoutInflater`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxmlfile, null);
```

and use `convertView` to declare your elements

Comment: can you be more specific? i can't figure out what you are trying to inflate here